# Memory mapping files within Containers

Tags: linux-kernel, containers, memory-mapped-files

Today we have an (batch) application that scales horizontally, and we are running multiple processes on multiple servers. All processes running on the same phys. machine *share* a large amount (~100 GB) of read-only memory with customer and contract related data which we load upfront and only ones into memory. Each phys server loads the same data into mem. We are loading the data into memory, because of performance reasons. We tried Redis and the like, but the performance dropped.

Since all data are read-only we are thinking of memory-mapping them instead. Each process would theoretically load the same files, but because we would memory-map them and they are read-only, the OS should only (lazy) load them on demand, only ones, and based on free phys memory. An additional advantage will be that each process is now completely decoupled from any other process, which has huge benefits in K8S/container environments.

Next step is, we want to put the processes (which are then using mmap) into containers. But we didn't find a way yet to bullet proof that the mmapped files are loaded only ones, despite the processes now being in different containers (if on the same server). To our current knowledge containers don't change the behavior of mmapping files, but we want to be sure.

Since different Linux distros and versions seem to have different means ... => we are using a fairly recent version of RedHat, but Ubuntu would be ok as well.  We found several different (linux) tools and means to list info about mmapped files, etc., e.g. which process is mmapping which file. May be we are just paranoid, but none of the information we found so far, clearly says: this file (or block of the file), loaded into this phys location, assigned to processes X, Y, and Z, and accessible via virtual addresses A, B, .. within these processes.

Any insight on whether containers change mmap behavior or not, and how to proof that mmapped files are loaded only ones, would be very much welcome.